# PHP Foreach and unsetting variable

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, pdo

I'm passing a PDO prepare parameter array into the foreach statement so that I can modify the data. I'm modifying some data based on the prefix. Here's the example from my code:

```
foreach($param as $key => $t)
{
    if(strpos($key,"int")===0)
    {
        $t = (int) $param[$key];
        $key = str_replace("int","",$key);
        unset($param[$key]);
        $param[$key] = $t;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to unset those array elements with int as prefix, and I can't execute query because of PDO error:

```
Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `unset($param[$key])` BEFORE you change `$key`.